# Override old object in array swift ios

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, find

I have an array of custom objects. For simplicity, lets say each object has 3 properties : `id`, `timestamp` and `text`. I am now obtaining a JSON response from my server which contains updated `text` for my objects in the array. I need to do the following :

1. Obtain the object with the given `id` from my array.
2. Set the `text` of the object to the updated `text` WITHOUT changing any of its other properties.
3. Override the old object with the new and updated one.

I have found the following extension which allows me to find the object in my array.

```
 extension CollectionType {
func find(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Generator.Element? {
    return try indexOf(predicate).map({self[$0]})
}
}
```

I am then using the following logic to obtain the item from the array.

```
let my_object =  questionImageObjects.find({$0.id== myId})
```

Now I set the text using `my_object.text = currText`.

The last step is to override the old object in the array with the updated one. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension `find` will return a *copy* of the original struct. Whatever you do to it, the original won't be affected. You can modify it through the index:

```
struct DataModel: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Int
    var timestamp: NSDate
    var text: String

    init(id: Int, timestamp: NSDate, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.text = text
    }

    // For debug purposes
    var description: String {
        get { return "( id = \(id), timestamp = \(timestamp), text = \(text) )" }
    }
}

// Initial data
var arr = [
    DataModel(id: 1, timestamp: NSDate(), text: "Anakin Skywalker"),
    DataModel(id: 2, timestamp: NSDate(), text: "Luke Skywalker")
]

// Now the server returns a JSON that says Anakin has turned to the Dark Side
let jsonString = "{ \"id\": 1, \"text\": \"Darth Vader\" }"
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])

// Update the text
if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject],
    let id = dict["id"] as? Int,
    let newText = dict["text"] as? String,
    let index = (arr.indexOf { $0.id == id }) {

    arr[index].text = newText
}

print(arr)
```

If those `if let`s confuse you, here's a step-by-step guide:

- `if let dict` checks that the JSON can be converted into a Dictionary
- `let id` checks that it has an `id` key of type `Int`
- `let newText` checks that it has a `text` key of type `String`
- `let index` checks that the array contains an element with that `id`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response